# gulp typescript semantic error report

Tags: typescript, gulp-typescript

I am running gulp-typescript and I receive an output like this.

```
[18:21:58] TypeScript: 1 semantic error 
TypeScript: emit succeeded (with errors)
```

With just running `tsc` I get no such output, what does the error mean and why I don't get a report on which line it occurs?

Comment: I'm afraid people can't help you without seeing your code